# How to get value of cell instead formula value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I use this library `openpyxl`.

And read data as:

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    print row[0].value
```

Instead value of cell I get formula: `=D42-D42*0.1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit: In latest version (3.0.6+) the api was changed to disable the user of the first option (`internal_value` property) and thus only the second option now works. (Thanks Akshat)**

You can either

1. Use `row[0].internal_value`.

Or

2. Use `data_only=True` when you load your workbook.
   (For example, `workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("yourxlsx.xlsx", data_only=True)`)

The second option is good when you are sure you don't wish to ever get the original formula from the workbook.

Comment: What to use to convert unicode to text? Now I get values in unicode like `u'25-371'`

Comment: What's wrong with unicode?

`str(unicode_string)` should do the trick nevertheless.

Comment: Using `row[0].internal_value` didn't work with the latest version  -`3.0.6`, had to go with `data_only` flag