# How to get the exact cell text instead of formula text from an excel sheet using pandas in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` and `pandas` to read values from an excel sheet into my python script. However, since there is a formula in some cells, it reads the 'formula' instead of the `value`.

How do I get the value of a cell instead of the formula of that cell?

For example, a cell with the formula - `=CONCATENATE(A23," ","gold")`, and its value is `'Ghana Gold'`. I want it to return `'Ghana Gold'`, however, at the moment I am getting `'=CONCATENATE(A23," ","gold")`.

P.S. for reference - I referred to https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-extract-information-from-your-excel-sheet-using-python-5f4f518aec49 for the data extraction part.

Comment: The question doesn't include any attempt to solve the problem. [Try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please show what you've tried and any specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For more information [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311994/how-to-get-value-of-cell-instead-formula-value)