# openpyxl giving None value when calling value of formula cell

Tags: python, openpyxl

When I'm trying to access the value of a cell that has a formula (`=E3*X`) I get `None` even with `data_only=True`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook("sales.xlsx", data_only=True)
sheet = book['sales']
print(sheet["G3"].value)
book.close()

>> Output: None
>> Cell's actual value: =E3*7.5 (60, E3=8)
```

Comment: please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311994/how-to-get-value-of-cell-instead-formula-value)

Comment: openpyxl can only provide a value if some other application or library has calculated one.